# Flexdashboard (RMarkdown) - Are tabsets possible within a sidebar?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

using RMarkdown for this particular project.

I have a sidebar within my flexdashboard. If possible, I'd like to have a tabset within the sidebar of my dashboard, however I'm having issues getting it to work. My tabbed data ends up in the main part of the dashboard instead of within the sidebar.

```
title: "Tabs in Sidebar"
Author: "Derek"
output: flexdashboard

Main Page {data-orientation=rows}
=================================

Column {.sidebar}
---------------------------------

## Sidebar Title {.tabset}

### Tab 1
Content for tab 1 goes here

### Tab 2
Content for tab 2 goes here

Row {}
---------------------------------
Main page content is here
```

I've also tried something like this as well, adding an extra hash to each title, but to no avail:

```
title: "Tabs in Sidebar"
Author: "Derek"
output: flexdashboard

Main Page {data-orientation=rows}
=================================

Column {.sidebar}
---------------------------------

### Sidebar Title {.tabset}

#### Tab 1
Content for tab 1 goes here

#### Tab 2
Content for tab 2 goes here

Row {}
---------------------------------
Main page content is here
```

Hoping someone with experience in RMarkdown can tell me if something like this would be possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if using tabs in a Flex sidebar is possible.  If you need more real-estate for widgets in a sidebar a possible alternative is the the dropdownButton of the shinyWidgets package.  It exposes and hides clusters of widgets.  Sample gallery here: http://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/  Select the dropdowns & sweetalert link to activate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late for you, but I had this problem today and found the answer.

````
---
title: "Tabs in Sidebar"
Author: "Derek"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Input {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------

Text for sidebar.

Row 
-------------------------------------

### Chart 1

```{r}

```


Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------

### Chart 2

```{r}

```

### Chart 3

```{r}

```
````

[image]

Comment: Not quite what I was going for... I was interested in having a table/chart within the "sidebar" on the left, that was tabbed so that I could change the table/chart in the sidebar by clicking a tab. But thank you for posting!

Answer (score 0):

I did this way, I added 3 tabsets in Sidebar

````
---

title: "Tabs in Sidebar"
Author: "Derek"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    source_code: embed
    theme: cerulean
---

```{r global, include=F}

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(flexdashboard)
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

```
# Sidebar {.sidebar data-width=350}
    
    
    ```{r }
    
    tabsetPanel(
            type = "pills",
       
    tabPanel("T-DXd",
    sliderInput("Dose.T.DXd", label="Dose Amount, mg/kg", min=1, max=8, value=5.4, step=0.2),
    sliderInput("Duration.T.DXd", label="Time Duration, months", min=1, max=24, value=4,step=1),
    sliderInput("Tau.T.DXd", label="Dose Interval, weeks", min=1, max=8, value=3)
    ),
    tabPanel("Dato.DXd",
    sliderInput("Dose.Dato.DXd", label="Dose Amount, mg/kg", min=1, max=8, value=6, step=0.2),
    sliderInput("Duration.Dato.DXd", label="Time Duration, months", min=1, max=24, value=4,step=1),
    sliderInput("Tau.Dato.DXd", label="Dose Interval, weeks", min=1, max=8, value=3)
    ),
    tabPanel("HER3-DXd",
    sliderInput("Dose.HER3.DXd", label="Dose Amount, mg/kg", min=1, max=8, value=5.6, step=0.2),
    sliderInput("Duration.HER3.DXd", label="Time Duration, months", min=1, max=24, value=4,step=1),
    sliderInput("Tau.HER3.DXd", label="Dose Interval, weeks", min=1, max=8, value=3)
    )
      )
```
````

[image]